# If i make changes to several tables and then db.SaveChanges() in entity framework does it save to all tables or none?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

If changes to one of the tables fail, will it save the changes to the other tables or will it just not save any changes at all?

Comment: Try it outWhy not try it out? The anser to your question is either yes or no, which both do not fit the rules for questions on SO well. Anyway it depends on the DBMS and in particlar on the transaction-handling. E.g. an update on MS-access (is this even possible with EF? I doubt so) *will* perform all the other operations whilst MySQL or Postgres won´t as they use a proper transaction.

Comment: EF6+ automatically wraps `SaveChanges()` in a transaction whether you set one up or not. So if one fails, everything is rolled back.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, all changes are made in one transaction, so if one fails there will not be any changes in database.